# Column vector notation inside text

Tags: notation, vectors

I am quite used to seeing a column vector denoted as $w=[w_1, w_2, w_3]^T$ inside text. However, I have recently met some people who do not think it is important to explicitly add the transpose symbol. Should it be considered a mistake or is it a common convenience to omit it? How should it be written in a research paper?

**Updated**:
I should also specify that I am talking about a scenario where two vectors are defined and multiplied together like $w^T x$. Mostly it is clear from context that the result should be a scalar or that it should be a 3x3 matrix. Is it enough to assume people understand it from context though?

Comment: This is my take: If what you have is a $3\times 1$ matrix, then you should add a transpose symbol to it. If it's "just" a general 3-dimensional vector there is no need.

Comment: Notation $\mathbf{x} = ( x_1 , x_2 , x_3 )$ is extremely common, and is often used for column vectors, too; i.e., $$\mathbf{x} = ( x_1 , x_2 , x_3 ) = \left [ \begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{array} \right ] = \left [ x_1 \; x_2 \; x_3 \right ]^T$$However, I'm not sure I've seen notation $\mathbf{w} = [ w_1 , w_2 , w_3 ]$ except to denote a row vector. (Granted, I am not a mathematician; I just use vectors and matrices as tools in describing and solving many different types of problems.) In my opinion, the people you met are careless and prone to errors; do not emulate them.